# How to parametrize class and function separately in pytest

Tags: pytest, fixtures, parametrize

I have a test class with 2 tests. How can I parametrize whole class while having one test parametrized additionally?

I need `test_b` executed 1 time for `param0` and 2 times for `param1`

```
Module threads.py
  Class TestThreads
     Function test_a[param0]
     Function test_b[param0-0]
     Function test_a[param1]
     Function test_b[param1-0]
     Function test_b[param1-1]
```

Comment: Write `param1` twice into the `parameterize` list?

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterise both class and methods individually and they stack together. For example, to get the outcome you describe, you can parameterise the class with param0, and parameterise test_b with param1:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param0", [0])
class TestThreads:

    def test_a(self, param0):
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [0, 1])
    def test_b(self, param0, param1):
        assert True
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I do it using fixtures?

Let say I have a dictionary which I use as a config for tests
`config = [
  {
    'param1': 'param1-val1',
    'param2': [
      'param2-val1', 
      'param2-val2'
    ]
  },
  {
    'param1': 'param1-val2',
    'param2': [
      'param2-val3', 
      'param2-val4'
    ]
  }
]`

How can I parametrize TestThreads suite with `param1` while `test_b` in it with `param2`?

Comment: Your config here is a list, how are you meaning to use this? One option is that you could create an auto-use fixture, and then parameterise the key to use. I'm not sure I fully understand your comment though.

Comment: I meant list of dictionaries, sorry.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the role of fixtures and parameterise. Fixtures are for providing background, constant, environmental things, a bit like "fittings and fixtures" in a house. Parameterise is where you can specify things which are specific to an individual test. Is your config confusing both of these? If feels like a parameterised list of fixtures (which is not a clean design)

Comment: @BenHorsburgh it is not the case when class param is scoped as "class". Asked a question related to a similar issue, what do you think? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235003/cyclic-parametrized-test-in-a-class-with-class-scoped-parameters)